# c++ code explanation after :: Operator

Tags: c++

Can someone tells me what is the `::CLOSE` in the following code :

```
Fight c;
c.type = Fight::CLOSE; //CLOSE can also become ::RANGE
```

I have to create the Fight class, but I have no idea of what is the `::CLOSE` part. 
I just know that `c.type` is a bool or an int.

Edit : An enum, not an int or a bool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fight` must be a `class` or a `struct` (probably a struct), so `CLOSE` is either a public constant or a value from an `enum` declared inside that class. That is:

```
class Fight {
public:
    const bool CLOSE = false;
    //...
};
```

or

```
class Fight {
public:
    enum Status {
        CLOSE
    }
    //...
};
```

Since you said that "c.type is a bool or an int", I think the first one is more likely to be the definition of your `Fight` class.

Answer (score 2):

It's more likely to be an `enum`, but okay.

Inside `Fight` will be:

```
enum Something
{
   CLOSE, RANGE
};
```

Then `Fight::CLOSE` and `Fight::RANGE` are integral constants with distinct values.

**Read about *enums* ("enumerated types") in your C++ book.**

The `::` syntax is (in this context) the way you access static members of the class. For example, you invoke static member functions like `Fight::someFunc()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a static member of the class `Fight`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a name that is declared in the scope of the `Fight` class. It probably should be declared as an enum.

```
struct Fight {
    enum Status {
        CLOSE,
        RANGE
    }

    Status type;
    //...
}
```

Enums export their names (`CLOSE`, `RANGE`) to the enclosing scope, i.e. the scope of the class in this case. When converted to `int`, `CLOSE` will yield 0 and `RANGE` will yield 1. (With this order of declaration)

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of the following

> 1. enum nested in a class .
> 2. static data member under public.
> 3. int/bool public data member.